# Datetime - 10 Hours

Tags: python, datetime

Consider:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
now
datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 6, 16, 6, 42, 812098)
```

How would I create a new datetime object (`past`) and minus `n` values from the hours?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `timedelta` in the `datetime` module:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
past = now - datetime.timedelta(hours=10)
```

Answer (score 8):

Use a [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#datetime.timedelta) object.

```
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 6, 16, 35, 50, 593000)
>>> ten_hours = datetime.timedelta(hours=10)
>>> now + ten_hours
datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 7, 2, 35, 50, 593000)
>>> now - ten_hours
datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 6, 6, 35, 50, 593000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#datetime.timedelta) object.

```
from datetime import datetime
back = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=10)
```