# In Python, how to I create a datetime with X hours?

Tags: python, datetime, time

How do I create the datetime that is 24 hours before NOW()?
48 before NOW()?
X hours or days before now??

Comment: Not-quite-exact duplicate of (and probably others): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688719/datetime-10-hours

Comment: This kind of question can be avoided by reading the documentation:  http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

Comment: -1 for not looking at docs or searching this website for the answer before posting the question.
A simple search "datetime hours" reveals a top result for exactly what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688719/datetime-10-hours

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def hours_ago(hours):
    return datetime.today() - timedelta(hours=hours)

def days_ago(days):
    return datetime.today() - timedelta(days=days)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24)
datetime.datetime(2010, 5, 18, 14, 5, 56, 128000)
```